# Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

On iOS 7.x (only), When I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue"]`, **while `self` is a `UINavigationController`**, I get the following `NSGenericException`:

> Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'MySegue'. Push
>   segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an
>   instance of UINavigationController.

Oddly enough, on iOS 8.x it works perfectly!

Every [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546122/nsgenericexception-reason-push-segues-can-only-be-used-when-the-source-contr) I saw regarding this exception tells you to embed the source view controller inside a UINavigationController, however in my case `self` is **already** a UINavigationController by itself.

It makes sense that `performSegueWithIdentifier:` would work when called on UINavigationController, and it does on iOS 8, so what's the problem on iOS 7??

Answer (score 0):

Very first reaction - How did you manage to create a segue from a `UINavigationController`??? In `Storyboard` you can create a relationship from `UINavigationController`, not a segue!

Well, I am amazed if it is working on iOS 8. But conceptually you cannot ask `UINavigationController` to `performSegueWithIdentifier` as a segue with push is just a graphical way of asking the sourceViewController to push segue's destinationViewController.

In this case, how are you trying to tell a `UINavigationController` to perform a segue? It does not have a navigationController, it itself is!!!

So I guess if it works on iOS 7 its a bug there.

**What you should be doing :**

Either perform the selector `-performSegueWithIdentifier` on the controller which is the source of the segue.

OR

Ask the UINavigationController to push your `destinationViewController`.