# Error when I click on the link

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When I click on the Button "Hello World" to go to a new page "View Controller" it gives me these error:

> "2015-12-27 16:48:36.939 Projects name [197:60b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues
>   can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance
>   of UINavigationController.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x30689f83 0x3ae3accf 0x33382c21 0x32edc037 0x32edbfd7 0x32edbfb1 0x32ec7717 0x32edba2f 0x32edb701
>   0x32ed66cb 0x32eab8cd 0x32ea9f77 0x3065520b 0x306546db 0x30652ecf
>   0x305bdebf 0x305bdca3 0x354c3663 0x32f0a14d 0x51385 0x3b347ab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)"

And

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?
I'm a newbie btw.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8JBn.jpg)

Comment: What code handles the button click?

Comment: "Hello World" button .. or I didn't get your question.

Comment: @sahaaboo Are you using Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, Main Storyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546122/nsgenericexception-reason-push-segues-can-only-be-used-when-the-source-contr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial `ViewController` is not inside a `UINavigationController`. So the push segue cannot be performed.

If you are using Storyboard you can easily fix that

1. in Xcode open the Storyboard file
2. select the initial `View Controller`
3. choose <kbd>Editor</kbd> > <kbd>Embed In</kbd> > <kbd>Navigation Controller</kbd>

Now it should work.

Comment: It works fine, thank you!
The thing is I have two pages, the second page got "back" on the top left, that's ok, but the first page got the same thing, how can I remove it?

Comment: If the first view controller got the `Back` button then I don't think it really is the first one. There should be a previous ViewController.

Comment: As the picture above, it showed a View Controller from "Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller" on the left of them, so I guess the second one, not the first I mentioned just before :/