# Push Action Segue from button to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am new to iOS app development and currently facing some issues segueing from a UIButton to a UIViewController. I did above in Main.storyboard by:

- selecting UIButton
- holding "control" and dragging to UIViewController
- Selecting "push" under Action Segue

After running this, i get below error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

---

Need help on resolving above error. Would appreciate it if solution comes with screenshots since i'm a newbie. Thanks!

After implementing @technerd solution, it still does not work. Below are images of the Navigation Controller menu and Action Segue Menu

[image]

[image]

Comment: As said: You can do a Push, only if you have a UINavigationController (the bar at the top that you can see on many apps to illustrate). Else, it's a Show, not a Push.

Comment: Under Action Segue, i have only 3 options: Push, Modal, Custom. There is no Show

Comment: Modal then. Note that the behavior is different because the context is. Also, you are using an Old version of XCode?

Comment: I am using Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546122/nsgenericexception-reason-push-segues-can-only-be-used-when-the-source-contr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From error logs it looks like you have not embedded `UINavigationController` as initial controller in you storyboard.

So first set `UINavigationController` as initial controller.
Because `push` and `pop` operation only performed when there is Navigation stack available.

1. Select first ViewController in Storyboard as per screen shot.
2. Then Editor -> EmbedIn -> NavigationController

To know how Navigation Stack works, go through this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--mobile-14052).

[image]

Once you set Navigation as InitialViewController, then set your first viewcontroller you want to show first as rootViewController of that navigation controller.

[image]

Then you can drag push from button to secondViewController to push from firstViewController to secondViewController.

[image]

As you can read in screenshot that `Push(Deprecated)`, so you have to use `Show` relationship. `Show` also perform same operation as `Push`.

**Update :**

As per your question update, you are facing that you are not able to show other Action Segue. Follow below steps to make it available.

1. Select your Navigation Controller in storyboard.
2. Enable `Use Trait Variations` option under `Interface Builder Document` on right side panel.

[image]

For more details check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated).

Comment: Thanks but how do i do that?

Comment: @PascalOkyereAdomako : Answer updated with all details.

Comment: Thanks @technerd for your detailed solution. I however tried this and still did not get the Action Segue option you have as shown in your images. I still get Push, Modal, Custom as the only options.

Comment: you can use push also.It would be better if you post screenshots in question.

Comment: @PascalOkyereAdomako : Answer updated for your `Action Segue` problem.

Comment: Woooooooo, thanks so much @technerd. It worked. Solution accepted

Answer (score 0):

Add Navigation Controller to your initial view

1. Select the initial view
2. Go To **Editor**--> **Embed In** --> **Navigation Controller**.

Answer (score 0):

Push segues are only available in UINavigationController types.
Try to add UINavigationController.
An easy way is:

[image]